# Finding the value of p for which inequality holds true

Tags: calculus, inequality

Find the value of $p$ for which

$$\cosh(x) \leq e^{px^2}$$ is true for all real values of x

Comment: Do you mean $\cosh(x) \leq e^{px^2}$ or $\cosh(x) \leq e^{(px)^2}$

Comment: I mean The first one but I couldn't get that in type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $p\geq{1\over2}$ we have
$$\cosh x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty{x^{2k}\over(2k)!}\leq \sum_{k=0}^\infty{x^{2k}\over 2^k\>k!}=e^{x^2/2}\leq e^{px^2}\qquad\forall\>x\in{\mathbb R}\ .$$
Assume now that $$0\leq p={1\over2}-\epsilon,\qquad \epsilon>0\ .$$ Then from
$$\lim_{x\to0}{e^{px^2}-1\over x^2}=p={1\over2}-\epsilon$$
it follows that there is a $\delta>0$ with
$$e^{px^2}\leq 1+{1-\epsilon\over2}x^2\qquad\bigl(|x|<\delta\bigr)\ .$$
On the other hand
$$\cosh x\geq 1+{x^2\over2}\qquad\forall x\in{\mathbb R}\ .$$
This shows that when $0\leq p<{1\over2}$ the envisaged inequality is wrong for $|x|\ll1$.

Therefore we can say that $\cosh x\leq e^{px^2}$ is true for all real $x$ iff $p\geq{1\over2}$.